# UILabel multiline issue with Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, uilabel

I have a label (multiline enable) and a button, I want my button to have a high priority for both content compression resistance and content hugging priority.

```
class MyCustomView: UIView {

private var containerView = UIView()
private let moreButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
private lazy var testLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.textColor = .red
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight.heavy)
    return label
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setUpViews()
    self.setUpConstraints()
}

public convenience init() {
    self.init(frame: .zero)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

private func setUpViews() {
    containerView.backgroundColor = .brown
    self.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    containerView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.backgroundColor = .white
    containerView.addSubview(testLabel)

    let string = "THIS HAS THE LOW TENDENCY TO TEST CAUGHT"
    testLabel.text = string
    testLabel.backgroundColor = .black
    createMoreButton()
}

private func createMoreButton() {
    moreButton.setTitle("MORE", for: .normal)
    moreButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    moreButton.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    moreButton.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    containerView.addSubview(moreButton)
}

private func setUpConstraints() {
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    testLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    moreButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
    containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true


    testLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    testLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    testLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: moreButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true


    moreButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
    moreButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
}
```

}

As you can see in the output, text should cover the right side of the frame then move to the next line
[Output image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeUjB.png)

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue, I have tried setting preferredmaxlayoutwidth but that didn't work

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Were you expecting "TEST" to be on the first line? I'm not real clear on what you're asking.

Comment: If line break mode is not important than change that to by Character wrapping,

`label.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping`

Comment: @Rob Yeah actually when I add the extra space to the string "TEST" move to the first line on the right space, this is actually should happen with this string as well.

Comment: @sreekanthm I need to done it as word wrapping